# How to use Redis command "bitcount" in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to use redis bitmap to save online user, use command "bitcount onlineUser" to count the number of online user.I use RedisTemplate to deal with redis. But I can't find any API in RedisTemplate to execute command "bitcount'.How can I  execute command "bitcount" in java? Any help will be appreciated.

```
 @Override
    public Boolean saveOnlineUser(Long userId) {
        ValueOperations<String,Object> ops = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
        return ops.setBit("onlineUser",userId,true);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getOnlineUser() {
        //I want to use Redis command "bitcount 'onlineUser'" here to count the number of online users
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "execute" method of RedisTemplate, for example:

```
public Long bitcount(final String key, final long start, final long end) {
    return redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Long>() {

        @Override
        public Long doInRedis(RedisConnection redisConnection) throws DataAccessException {

            return redisConnection.bitCount(key.getBytes(), start, end);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use spring, you can use `bitCount` operation like below.

```
redisTemplate.execute { connection ->
        connection.stringCommands().bitCount(key.toByteArray())
}
```